# How to set Integrated Windows Authentication in SignalR for some but not all hubs

Tags: c#, signalr, windows-authentication

I need to use Windows Authentication for a hub, but since Im working in a bigger system, I can only access the SignalR Pipeline over the GlobalHost.

Ive tried using `AuthorizedAttribute`, but that does not set the Identity, since there is no Autorization Module registered.

Ive tried setting `GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();`

That set the Identity, but since it sets Authorization globally, other Hubs can not connect.

Finally, I tried adding a custom Authorization module, that should only apply to the one hub I want.
But as soon as I make an exception for one Hub, the Identity isnt set again, and I get an UnAuthrorized response from the Authorized Hub.

Answer (score 0):

I usually put the authentication attribute on top of my hub class.

```
 [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
 public class myChat : Hub 
 {
 }
```

this is token-based authentication and you need to configure your send your authentication token from the client.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that my OWIN startup did not include allowing Windows auth to the HttpListener that was set up (my Hub was set up in a Windows Service, not IIS). The `AuthenticationSchemes` line below was the key to getting this working.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        if (app.Properties.TryGetValue(typeof(HttpListener).FullName, out object listener))
        {
            ((HttpListener)listener).AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
        }
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR("/sfm", new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableDetailedErrors = true,
        });
    }
```